# AngularJS custom directive with ngModel binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive for displaying a formatted address. I've written the following code to use the new directive, but it doesn't work. My account controller (not shown) works fine, and the billingAddress.Line1 is shown correctly. However, my address directive does not render anything.

I've included the directive code with my html, although I expect to move it to a separate .js file for reuse. Could someone explain what I've done wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-address.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module('ng-directives', []);

      app.directive("ngAddress", function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            address: '=ngModel'
          },
          template: "<div>{{address.Line1}}</br><span>{{address.Line1}}</br></span>{{address.city}}, {{address.state}} {{address.postCode}}</div>"
        };
      });

    })();
  </script>
</head>

<body class="container" ng-controller="AccountController as account">
  <div>{{account.model.billingAddress.line1}}</div>
  <ng-address ng-model="account.model.billingAddress"></ng-address>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get started, the example was incomplete.

- I changed the angular module to `myApp`
- I added a controller `AccountController`
- using `as` in ng-controller didn't work. I'm not sure whether this should work, but I never use it.

The major problem in the directive was the bad use of `ng-model`. You should pass it to `require`, not to the scope. It is then passed to the `link` function, where the `$render` function is implemented.

You will probably also want to push a function to `$viewChangeListeners`.

For more details, see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Lastly the template contained `</br>`, which is invalid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

      app.controller('AccountController', function($scope) {
        $scope.model = {
          billingAddress: {
            line1: 'somewhere far far away',
            city: 'Dark side of the moon',
            state: 'Top secret',
            postCode: '1337XD'
          }
        };
      });

      app.directive("ngAddress", function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          require: '?ngModel',
          template: "<div>{{address.line1}}<br><span>{{address.line1}}<br></span>{{address.city}}, {{address.state}} {{address.postCode}}</div>",
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$render = function() {
              scope.address = ngModel.$modelValue;
            };
          }
        };
      });

    })();
  </script>
</head>

<body class="container" ng-controller="AccountController">
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="model.billingAddress.line1"/>
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="model.billingAddress.city"/>
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="model.billingAddress.state"/>
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="model.billingAddress.postCode"/>
  <ng-address ng-model="model.billingAddress"></ng-address>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're right, my code was incomplete. The app and controller were defined in a separate file (app.js). As you pointed out though, the major problem had been my use of ngModel. Also, I had to get the app by name, which I hadn't done. After making the modifications, I was able to get it to run. Thanks.